# Docker-compose "exec: \"/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh\": permission denied"

Tags: docker-compose, alpine-linux

This is based on https://testdriven.io/courses/microservices-with-docker-flask-and-react/

I'm running a docker file that will point to entrypoint.sh.

The `docker-compose-f docker-compose-dev.yml build run` successfully
But running `docker-compose-f docker-compose-dev.yml up` shows

```
ERROR: for users  Cannot start service users: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh\": permission denied": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I did try to run on interactive mode with `docker run -it –tty users_app:latest sh`.
Running `./entrypoint.sh` did work. 
But it didn't work with docker-compose.

Does anybody have the same issue?

This is my docker-compose-dev.yml, Dockerfile-dev, and entrypoint.sh

docker-compose-dev.yml

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  users:
    build:
      context: ./services/users
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/users:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=project/__init__.py
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - APP_SETTINGS=project.config.DevelopmentConfig
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_dev
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_test    
    depends_on:
      - users-db

  users-db:  
    build:
      context: ./services/users/project/db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5435:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

Dockerfile-dev

```
# base image
FROM python:3.6.5-alpine

# install dependencies
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python-dev musl-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev && \
    apk add netcat-openbsd

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add and install requirements
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# add app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# add entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

# run server
#USER root
#RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Waiting for postgres..."
while ! nc -z users-db 5432; do
    sleep 0.1
done

echo "PostgresSQL started"

python manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Running the `chmod +x /usr/src/entrypoint.sh` in the source directory does work.
Docker is it's own system file, but it copies everything (including permission) from the source directory.

However, i couldn't understand, why running the `RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh` in the dockerfile doesn't work

Answer (score 7):

Check the permission of `entrypoint.sh` in host computer, cause it would copy everything to container.

```sh
chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
```

Then rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing on a windows box, then it could be a line terminator issue.  When bash runs your script, it does not handle the windows style /r/n line terminators.

Try running this locally on your windows dev box...
`dos2unix entrypoint.sh`

This will change the line terminators to unix style.  Then rebuild the container.  This cleared up the problem for me.